# typescript declare map type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using typescript and I need to decare a type to describe this format of data:

```
{
  "apple": [{"color": "red","taste": "good"}, {"color":"green", "taste": "bad"}],
  "banana":[{"color": "yellow","taste": "okay"}]
}
```

This is what I have right now, I declared a type Fruit and made it a map using Record and then I added string as key(which is going to be fruit name like apple, banana) and declared a type/interface `FruitDescription` class as Fruit's value.

```
type Fruit = Record<string, FruitDescription>

interface FruitDescription {
  color: string,
  taste: string
}
```

With this set up I am not able to deduce the type of the data mentioned above.

Can someone give me any better suggestion for solving this kind of issue? Thank you for help.

Comment: The hardest problems are those, where you're trying to find an error, but it doesn't exist.

I think this is perfectly fine, except you're missing interface before FruitDescription

Comment: > but I feel something is not right

Does it mean that it compiles? or is it just a feeling?

Comment: FruitDescription should be an interface or type

Comment: How about this being a generic map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an array of fruit descriptions which is missing in your type annotation.

```
type Fruit = Record<string, FruitDescription[]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with what **AdamExchange** already mentioned, If you have an interface defined like below

```
interface FruitDescription {
  color: string;
  taste: string;
}
```

You could also try the below two options -

```
const m: { [name: string]: FruitDescription[] } = {
   "apple": [{"color": "red","taste": "good"}, {"color":"green", "taste": "bad"}],
   "banana":[{"color": "yellow","taste": "okay"}]
};
```

***Or*** you could use `ES6/Typescript` `Map` -

```
let map : Map<string, FruitDescription[]> = new Map<string, FruitDescription[]>();

map.set("apple", [{"color": "red","taste": "good"}, {"color":"green", "taste": "bad"}])
map.set( "banana", [{"color": "yellow","taste": "okay"}])

console.log(map.get("apple"));
```